# How to count sequences that belong a cluster? (from cd-hit output)

Tags: bash, perl, sequence

I have the cd-hit output, I would like to obtain the number of sequences that belongs to a same cluster.

My input:

> Cluster 1
>
> 0   33aa, >abu-miR-101a:1-8... *
>
> Cluster 2
>
> 0   33aa, >abu-miR-103:1-8... *
>   1   33aa, >NODE_603086_length_... at 100.00%
>
> 2   33aa, >NODE_603086_length_... at 100.00%
>
> 3   33aa, >NODE_603086_length_... at 100.00%
>
> 4   33aa, >NODE_603086_length_... at 100.00%
>
> Cluster 3
>
> 0   33aa, >abu-miR-10543:1-8... *
>
> 1   33aa, >abu-miR-10543:1-8... at 100.00%
>
> Cluster 4
>
> 0   33aa, >abu-miR-10544:1-8... *
>
> Cluster 5
>
> 0   33aa, >abu-miR-10545-5p:1-... *
>
> I would like this output:
>
> Cluster 1 1
>
> Cluster 2 5
>
> Cluster 3 2
>
> Cluster 4 1
>
> Cluster 5 1

I just want the name of cluster in a first column and the number of sequences that this cluster contains in a second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be good for you to show us what you've tried, and also I'm not sure how you got 5 sequences associated with Cluster 2 (there are only 4 in your output, but I notice that #1 is missing from the list, so maybe it's a copy / paste error?).  But, one way to do it in Perl, since you've included that tag, is to read the file line by line, and if you see a 'Cluster' string make it a hash key, else (for subsequent lines), iterate the count like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %results;
my $cluster;

while (<DATA>) {
    if ($_ =~ /Cluster/) {
        chomp($cluster = $_);
        $results{$cluster} = 0;
    } else {
        $results{$cluster}++;
    }
}

print "$_\t$results{$_}\n" for (sort { $a cmp $b } keys %results);

__DATA__
Cluster 1
0 33aa, >abu-miR-101a:1-8... *
Cluster 2
0 33aa, >abu-miR-103:1-8... * 1 33aa, >NODE_603086_length_... at 100.00%
2 33aa, >NODE_603086_length_... at 100.00%
3 33aa, >NODE_603086_length_... at 100.00%
4 33aa, >NODE_603086_length_... at 100.00%
Cluster 3
0 33aa, >abu-miR-10543:1-8... *
1 33aa, >abu-miR-10543:1-8... at 100.00%
Cluster 4
0 33aa, >abu-miR-10544:1-8... *
Cluster 5
0 33aa, >abu-miR-10545-5p:1-... *
```

I've made a lot of assumptions here (for example, new Clusters will always start with a line containing the string "Cluster #" followed by subsequent lines containing sequences related to each "Cluster").  This is just a basic example of one quick way to think about it, and you'll likely have to tweak this to meet your final needs.

Comment: _I'm not sure how you got 5 sequences associated with Cluster 2_ Change `$results{$cluster}++;` to `$results{$cluster} += tr/>//`

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! It works! I just add a sort to obtain the results sorted by numbers. Like this:

```
perl count-cluster.pl | sort -k 2 -g | head
```

Then the head result:

> Cluster 0  64
>
> Cluster 1  1
>
> Cluster 2  5
>
> Cluster 3  2
>
> Cluster 4  1
>
> Cluster 5  1
>
> Cluster 6  1
>
> Cluster 7  3
>
> Cluster 8  1
>
> Cluster 9  1

Thank you so much! There are more than 3000 lines in my files, and I need this results for three differents conditions, that helps a lot! Thank you!